# Get Dailymotion video desctiption from URL

Tags: json, api, url, video, dailymotion-api

I'm trying to extract video information from Dailymotion video URLs. I'm able to get information such as thumbnail, title, channel and arthur from a valid Dailymotion API url.

eg https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x7lni3_mario-kart-remi-gaillard_fun

Anyhow this doesn't output the video description. Is there any way to extract the description from an API URL or any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please have a look at the [Dailymotion Graph API documentation](http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/graph-api.html) and the [Dailymotion Graph API Reference](http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/reference.html) because this isn't how it works. If you need some specific fields from an object, you need to specify it in your request, like this:

```
https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x7lni3?fields=id,title,description
```

[Here](http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/obj-video.html#fields) is all the information you can extract from a video.

Comment: Thank you very much Dailymotion. I think I have missed that API doc. Just wondering are you from official Dailymotion?